# Postgres how to maintain order of rows using CTEs

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables

```
students:

      id   | name | age
      1      abc   20
      2      xyz   21

scores:

   id | studentid | marks
    1       1        20
    2       2        22
    3       2        20
    4       1        22
    5       1        20
```

where `studentid` is foreign key to students table

When a do

```
select studentid 
from scores 
where marks=20;
```

I get the following result
    `1, 2, 1`

But if want the name of the student name and when I do a join using

```
 select t1.name 
 from students t1 
 inner join scores t2 on t1.id = t2.studentid 
 where t2.marks=20;
```

I get `xyz,abc,abc` Though the ouput is correct is there any way I can maintain the order in which scores are listed in the scores table? I should get `abc,xyz,abc` as output. I tried using subquery as well

```
 SELECT name 
 FROM students 
 WHERE ID IN ( select studentid from scores where marks=20) ;
```

but that also did not give me correct order. How can this be achieved using CTEs (common table expressions)? I tried the follownig cte but it did not work

```
with cte as(
    select t2.id, t1.name 
     from students t1 
     inner join scores t2 on t1.id = t2.studentid 
     where t2.marks=20)
select name from cte order by id
```

Comment: The ***only*** way to get a guaranteed order is to use an `order by`. It's unclear to me which order you what, but maybe `order by t2.id`?

Comment: No order by will sort either ascending or descending on any column. As you can see I want to maintain order as there in scores table. student id 1,3,5. Its a coincidence that 1,3,5 are in ascending order.

Comment: There is no such thing as the "order in the scores table". Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** "sorted". The only (really: the **only**) way to get a defined order in your result is to use an `order by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by a column not present in select list:

```
select t1.name 
from students t1 
inner join scores t2 on t1.id = t2.student_id 
where t2.marks=20
order by t2.id; 

 name 
------
 abc
 xyz
 abc
(3 rows)
```